# Posting SNS messages to AWS_IAM authenticated Api Gateway endpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, aws-api-gateway

1. I've created SNS topic
2. I've created API Gateway endpoint that invokes Lambda function
3. I've created topic HTTPS subscription that points to API Gateway endpoint

Problem: everything works fine when AUTH=none, but when i enabled AUTH=AWS_IAM, neither subscription nor messages are delivered to my lambda. They also wont show up in Lambda OR Gateway cloudwatch logs as it's usually the case with authentication errors.

Questions:

- What's the identity delivered by HTTPS endpoint to AWS_IAM so it doesn't allows it ( my first thought was to relay SNS posters token but it doesn't seem be the case )
- I couldn't find any way to associate HTTPS endpoint with any identity, is there a way?
- There are lots of information about delivering SNS to SQS or Gateway to SNS, but couldn't find any information about achieving what i try to do.
- Is there any method to debug AWS_IAM authentication problems? Documentation i've seen advices to "check priviliges" which is something i've been doing for many hours but i have no more ideas.

I'd be glad to hear any ideas from you, thanks.

Comment: How did you subscribe the API Gateway endpoint to the SNS topic...I have read the docs (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/SendMessageToHttp.html#SendMessageToHttp.prepare) but didnt understand much.

Comment: The same way you POST your messages to any HTTPS endpoint. You just need to add extra code to confirm subscription based on event.Type, then you need to trigger GET event.SubscribeURL. Sorry for missing your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you may have seen in the docs, SNS can only do Basic/Digest Auth http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/SendMessageToHttp.html

There is a section in the docs about verifying the validity of the message but that is code you'd have to write yourself or lift from one of the SNS SDKs on the backend. There really isn't any way to get SNS to sign the request with AWS SigV4, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you let the Lambda function subscribe directly to the SNS topic (without going through API Gateway)?

That should be straightforward: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-lambda.html

Comment: That's most definitely a valid approach, idea behind that was to have rest-only api open for any kind of client (not necessarily aware of aws). Unfortunately on this stage i cannot alter that design.

Comment: After reading the documentation for SNS again: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/SendMessageToHttp.html I seriously doubt that SNS can send IAM authenticated HTTPS POST requests to API Gateway endpoints. The docs talk about Basic and Digest Authentication only, but IAM is something different. Another pointer is that there is no way to configure a principal for SNS POSTs. (Also, going through API gateway incurs additional costs that are unnecessary if the "client"/publisher is SNS. )

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete link which will help you in solving your authentication problem. https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/iam-authentication-api-gateway/

If it's an "Check privileges" issue, then your IAM user doesn't have any sufficient access to the resources to make any changes.

Comment: I've seen that link and other parts of my API work fine. The only problem is that SNS HTTPS subscription doesn't forward credentials of user who sent SNS message. In other words i don't know what is my user, or how do i assign user to HTTPS subscription.